# Check if file exists in list of directories

Tags: python

I have a list of directories, and a file name. I'd like to check if this file name exists in **any** of the directories, if it does exist then the code passes, if not then we'll error out. I'm having some trouble with the next step though, here's what I have.

```
for value in d.values():
    for path in value:
        if exists(path + '/' + filename):
            print 'True'
        else:
            print 'False'
```

Here's the list of my test output:

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
True
True
True
```

As you can see this fails a lot, but there is some passing cases here, the fact that is passes once is good enough for me, but I'm not sure how to translate this into proper python logic.

Basically what'd I'd like to do is

```
if file exists in any list_of_paths:
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'False'
```

Can anyone advise how to go about this?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly then you could just break out of the for loop after the first match, so beneath ``print True`` put a line with ``break``. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for ``break`` and ``continue``. Sorry if I misread the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os

print(any(os.path.exists(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
          for directories in d.values()
          for dirpath in directories))
```

Answer (score 2):

One very simple solution is to wrap this code in a function that returns `True` as soon as it finds a path under which the file exists.

Comment: Very practical, but it's also quite simply expressed as `any` plus a generator expression, which I prefer.

Comment: Yes, but this requires using somewhat more sophisticated Python concepts than a simple function.

Comment: I agree, and I often try to walk that line in my answers, but these are such basic python building blocks that I come down on the other side on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace where you call exists with os.path.exists(path), and your code should pretty much work.

Answer (score 1):

if you already have the folder names in a list and want to filter folders that have a particular file name in them, you can use a list comprehension thus:

```
import os
listOfFolders = [*contains the folderpaths*]
validFolders = [folder for folder in listOfFolders if 'badFile.txt' not in os.listdir(folder)]
```

this returns a list of folders that don't have `badFile.txt` in them. alternatively, you can omit the `not` if you want folders that have `badFile.txt` in them.